# How did Panini, Jaimini and Pingala die?

Tags: pancharatra, jaimini, panini

Mitrasampati is the second tantra of Panchatantra. It delves into the acquisition of friends. In the main story, an argument takes place between the mouse Hiranyaka  and the crow Laghupathanaka on natural enemies. Hiranyaka states that no good can come out of friendship between natural enemies. He then goes on to give [examples](https://jneyam.com/dharmashastra/panchatantra-story21/) of Panini, Jaimini and Pingala

> But a lion took away the life of Panini(The most celebrated of Sanskrit grammarians. He lived in the 7th century BC and was a native of Salatura near Attock in the North West Frontier Provinces. Lions were fairly common in North India in ancient times) the grammarian, an elephant killed Jaimini(A pupil of Vyasa and the teacher of the Sama Veda) the philosopher, an alligator tore to pieces Pingala the Vedic scholar; these instances will show that neither virtue nor accomplishment will be a protection against the lower animals who are passionate and sunk in ignorance and cannot appreciate merit or virtue’

My question is whether the aforementioned deaths have been detailed in any scripture or scholarly work.

Comment: Only Pañcatantra mentions the strange deaths of these three. No other scripture as to my knowledge gives the information of how they died.